# Understanding throughput of simd sum implementation x86

Tags: x86, simd

I have the following loop in asm:

```
.LBB5_5:
 vaddpd  ymm0, ymm0, ymmword, ptr, [rdi, +, 8*rcx]
 vaddpd  ymm1, ymm1, ymmword, ptr, [rdi, +, 8*rcx, +, 32]
 vaddpd  ymm2, ymm2, ymmword, ptr, [rdi, +, 8*rcx, +, 64]
 vaddpd  ymm3, ymm3, ymmword, ptr, [rdi, +, 8*rcx, +, 96]
 add     rcx, 16
 cmp     rax, rcx
 jne     .LBB5_5
```

This is part of a bigger function which calculates the sum of of an `[f64]` array in Rust.

I benchmarked this code with the criterion crate and get that `1 000 000 000` doubles take `200 000 000` cycles on my Rocket Lake CPU (i7 11700K)

In various sources I find that the latency of a floating point addition is 4 cycles on this CPU.
This would mean that each of the `vaddpd` can only run every 4th cycle, because they carry a dependency of the previous sum. This would mean I can only do 4 double addition per cycle at max.

My measurement shows it does 5 additions per cycle. (It uses the `RDTSC` instruction to measure it, I am not sure if this can be problematic)

I mostly want to understand what is going on and test how well I understand the CPU pipeline.

Comment: The code you posted is not quite correct because of the extra commas. The 4 `vpaddpd` instructions use separate accumulators, which means they can execute in parallel. Given that on Rocket Lake `vpaddpd` reverse throughput is 0.5, it means up to 2 of these additions may start per clock. Depending on how long the loop is, and whether the source data is hot in cache, memory throughput may be the limiting factor here.

Comment: @AndreySemashev This is just the representation `cargo asm` gives me, it's not a handcrafted loop.
I know that these 4 instructions can be run in parallel, but this should give me only 4 times 4doubles per 4 cycles. I observe faster execution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you’re observing 5 additions per cycle because you’re using `RDTSC` to measure.

For the last decade or so, RDTSC instruction does not count CPU cycles. Instead, it measures wallclock time using base frequency of the CPU.

[Your CPU](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/212047/intel-core-i711700k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz/specifications.html) has base frequency 3.6 GHz, and max turbo frequency is 5.00 GHz. If you run a short test your CPU gonna run at turbo frequency, however the counter measured with RDTSC still runs at base frequency.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. When I disable turbo I get 260 000 000 cycles which is compatible with 4 additions per cycle

Comment: *RDTSC still runs at base frequency.* - Or some frequency close to it, e.g. 4008 MHz on my i7-6700k (base 4 GHz, boost 4.2 GHz).  Or on some CPUs, not even close to the base frequency, e.g. some mobile Ice Lake CPUs that support TDP-up and TDP-down.  [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/108701988).  Hmm, I wonder how that works on Alder Lake with E-cores and P-cores?  Presumably the TSCs are still synced across all cores like typical multicore CPUs, so one set of cores will have a TSC that's basically unrelated to its core clocks.